# Mysql Max Questions and Mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I have an environment where I have a maximum of 10 questions per hour. I am trying to do a mysqldump however everytime I do this I hit the exceeded questions despite only doing a single command.

Currently I am using

```
 mysqldump --single-transaction=TRUE --skip-lock-tables  --quick -u username -h example.com -p databasename >  2017-11-08-databasename.sql
```

Previously until adding the arguments `--single-transaction=TRUE --skip-lock-tables` I would get the following error:

```
has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 10) when using LOCK TABLES
```

Since adding these i have resolved that error but I am now getting

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute '/*!40100 SET @@SQL_MODE='' */':
```

It appears that mysql is doing a number of operations before dumping the database and these are exceeding the max quetsions. How can I dump the database without these command being executed?

Please note I am unable to increase the `max_questions` and of course I am only able to test one thing each hour.

**Update**

Command tried:

```
mysqldump -e --single-transaction=TRUE --skip-lock-tables  --quick --compact --no-data -u username -h example.com -p databasename >  2017-11-08-databasename.sql
```

Error:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SET SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1'
```

Comment: Did you try mysqldump --compact ?

Comment: @olegsv I have updated the question as I have now tried this with a few other flags and the result is unfortunately the same.

Answer (score 0):

I just happened across this question whilst looking for something else and although it's old. I note it hasn't been answered, so hopefully this **unexpert** view might help someone, if not the OP.

From what I've read mysqldump is simply a utility that writes and then executes all of the individual queries that are needed to full export the database.

All I can suggest then is that you write the individual queries yourself and execute them in batches of 10. That's probably not much use as a long term solution (unless you can create a number of overnight jobs that trigger every hour) but at least it would allow you to extract the full database and re-home it somewhere with a more 'liberal' max questions policy.